# Cambiar fondo blanco a canvas con formato JPEG

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

alguien podría ayudarme con el siguiente problema:
Estoy dibujando una firma en un canvas con javascript, pero al momento de convertir la imagen en JPEG esta me queda con el fondo negro, necesito que el fondo sea blanco y el dibujo con azul, mi código es el siguiente:

```js
function crearDibujo(){

 //Indicamos que aun no existe la firma
 ver_firma_responsable = false;

 //
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-firma-responsable');
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 //
 canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
 canvas.height = 350;
 //resetCanvas();
 // Manejadores de eventos
 //document.getElementById('btn-limpiar-firma-responsable').onmouseup = resetCanvas;
 
 // Eventos
 canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
  var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];
  draw(touchobj.clientX,touchobj.clientY);
  bandera = true; 
  e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
  
 canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
  if (bandera) {
   var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];
   draw(touchobj.clientX, touchobj.clientY);
   e.preventDefault();
  }

  //Indicamos que ya existe la firma
  ver_firma_responsable = true;

    }, false);
 
 canvas.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
       bandera = false;
    e.preventDefault();
    }, false);

}

function draw(x, y) {

 //var posCanvas = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 x = x - 10; //posCanvas.left;
 y = y - 86; //posCanvas.top;

 if (bandera) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#0066ff';
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
  ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
 }

 lastX = x; lastY = y;

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito que el fondo sea blanco como lo explique anteriormente, ya que estoy adjuntando esa imagen a un pdf con jspdf

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado encontre en otros post lo siguiente:

```js
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
 var data  = imgData.data;
 
 for(var i=0;i<data.length;i+=4){
     if(data[i+3]<255){
         data[i]=255;
         data[i+1]=255;
         data[i+2]=255;
         data[i+3]=255;
     }
 }

 ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
```

esto me funciono para mi.